# not able to dual boot to windows 7 after installing ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, grub2, dual-boot

I installed ubuntu 12.04 after installing windows 7. I have 2 hard disks, one SSD and another HDD. Windows was installed in the HDD, and I wanted ubuntu on my SSD. I chose to have boot files in the SSD where I had installed ubuntu. Initially after the installation it didn't show the dual boot option and directly booted to ubuntu. But after going through some suggestions I used boot-repair and got GRUB repaired/installed. But when I restarted again in the boot options I didn't find the Windows 7 option. I fear that I have accidentally deleted the windows boot files. This is the link I got after boot-repair:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1615740/

Comment: I don't think you have deleted anything. For some reason os-prober is detecting your windows installation on /dev/sdb1. From the log file "Windows not detected by os-prober on sdb1."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it a bit more, I suspect that running the following command in the Windows 7 installation CD repair console will allow os-prober to find your windows installation.

```
bootrec /fixboot
```

After running the command. Reboot, you will most likely still only boot into Ubuntu. So then rerun the boot-repair script. If you've got any trouble please submit the new pastebin.

Comment: I saw this answer after I wrote the longer answer below, but I think this might provide the **real and permanent solution** provided that Windows setup/recovery CD is available and that it doesn't override Grub (dual-boot menu).

Answer (score 0):

You can try rebooting after **manually modifying your grub menu very, very carefully** by opening **Terminal** and entering `sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg`, and inserting the following text at the end of the **/etc/grub.d/40_custom** section, immediately above the last line containing "**END /etc/grub.d/40_custom**":

```
menuentry 'Windows 7' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-9E8A1E4F8A1E2475' {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='hd1,msdos2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos2 9E8A1E4F8A1E2475
else
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9E8A1E4F8A1E2475
fi
chainloader +1
}
```

If this works, you can **make this menu entry permanent** by performing the same insertion on the file "**/etc/grub.d/40_custom**" with this **Terminal** command: `sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom`

This might serve as a **workaround** if this is because your Ubuntu/Grub somehow cannot detect Windows.